# Как мне в selenium сделать чтоб если страница не загружается - закрыть браузер

Tags: python, selenium

```python
driver = webdriver.Firefox(desired_capabilities=capabilities, executable_path='/home/alexandr/geckodriver')
driver.get("https://2ip.ru/")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "d_clip_button"))
    )
except TimeoutException:
    driver.quit()
```

Я сейчас настраиваю прокси, и если плохое попадается - страница просто висит и код зависает на строек `driver.get(...)`.

Comment: [По правилам форума SO нужно отметить ответ как верный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) если он решает вашу задачу.

Answer (score 2):

У каждого драйвера есть таймаут на загрузку страницы, по дефолту 30 секунд, настраивается с помощью метода [`WebDriver.set_page_load_timeout`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.set_page_load_timeout). Пример:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(1)

try:
    driver.get('https://cnn.co.jp')
except TimeoutException:
    driver.quit()
```

Окно браузера откроется, но из-за огромной задержки от Европы до Японии через секунду кинется таймаут и программа завершится.